# Problem with " Import the project into your OMNeT++ IDE workspace"

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am currently installing Veins for my SUMO and OMNet++ and I ran into the issue by import the project into your OMNeT++ IDE workspace. I did as the tutorial told to "clicking File > Import > General: Existing Projects into Workspace and selecting the directory you unpacked the module framework to." and at the window with selecting the folder I chose the directory veins-5.2, and I can't select this and press finish.

Which step could be wrong?

Comment: What is your OS? Does your folder (where you unpacked Veins) contain these files: `.cproject` and `.project`? Note that in Linux you must use `ls -a` to show these files.

Comment: I solved the problem with shutting down the original workspace and built a new one. It seemed that my original workspace has already contained the Veins folder. Everything works finely now.